# How to get component's name that calls plugin's method inside Nuxt plugin

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I have Nuxt.js plugin like that:

```js
    export default (ctx, inject) => {
      inject('doSomething', {
        method1: function(data) {
          ...
          console.log(data, componentName);
        },
        method2: function(data) {
          ...
          console.log(data, componentName);
        },
      });
    };
```

So, please help me find a way to log component's name (if any), named as ***componentName*** in plugin,
when in calls:

```js
    this.$doSomething.method1('data to display');
```

Comment: Not sure if this will work well with nuxt plugin, but generally it's `this.$options.name`

Comment: I know about this.$options.name inside component, but I need the value inside plugin without the need to call plugin's methods like 
this.$doSomething.method1('data to display', this.$options.name);

Comment: You'd need to pass `this` to method1 somehow, likely as an argument. This could be XY problem, consider reasking with your case explained. You probably need doSomething to be a function instead to access correct `this`, or else